# How to set a Swift Package in Debug Configurations only using Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

With `CocoaPods`, we can set the following configurations:

```
pod 'SourceModel', :configurations => ['Debug']
```

Is there any way to do the same with Swift Package Manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember a proposal request that was supposed to support it and was supposed to be implemented in Swift 5.3 but I'm not sure it was fully implemented. Nevertheless, here the link to the proposal request

[SE‐0273](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0273-swiftpm-conditional-target-dependencies.md#proposed-solution)